# Problem with Forms and Labels in Bootstrap & React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I'm currently building a React website with bootstrap. The big Problem I'm having right now is that the Labels for my Inputs are always centered. I'm for the life of me not able to get them left aligned :D

Below is the Code I'm using. It's straight from the bootstrap example, except for the changes to use it with react like class -> className and for -> htmlFor

```
    <div className="input-group mb-3 mt-3">
      <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2"/>
      <span className="input-group-text" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
    </div>

    <div class="form mb-3">
      <label htmlFor="basic-url" class="form-label">Your vanity URL</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-text" id="basic-addon3">https://example.com/users/</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="basic-url" aria-describedby="basic-addon3 basic-addon4"/>
      </div>
      <div class="form-text" id="basic-addon4">Example help text goes outside the input group.</div>
    </div>
```

and here is what it looks like
[centered label problem]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmvhV.png)

In every single example, the label is left-aligned. I tried different combinations of form-control and other annotations, but it seems like I'm the only person with this problem.

Comment: Have you determined what CSS is causing it to align center? What have you tried to left-align it?